# How to parse Camel Case to human readable string?

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, camelcasing

Is it possible to parse camel case string in to something more readable.

for example:

- LocalBusiness = Local Business
- CivicStructureBuilding = Civic Structure Building
- getUserMobilePhoneNumber = Get User Mobile Phone Number
- bandGuitar1 = Band Guitar 1

**UPDATE**

Using [simshaun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254093/how-to-parse-camel-case-to-human-readable-string/6254138#6254138) regex example I managed to separate numbers from text with this rule:

```
function parseCamelCase($str)
{
    return preg_replace('/(?!^)[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]|[0-9]{1,}/', ' $0', $str);
}

//string(65) "customer ID With Some Other JET Words With Number 23rd Text After"
echo parseCamelCase('customerIDWithSomeOtherJETWordsWithNumber23rdTextAfter');
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are some examples in the user comments of str_split in the PHP manual.

From [Kevin](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#81836):

```
<?php
$test = 'CustomerIDWithSomeOtherJETWords';

preg_replace('/(?!^)[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]/', ' $0', $test);
```

And here's something I wrote to meet your post's requirements:

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    'LocalBusiness' => 'Local Business',
    'CivicStructureBuilding' => 'Civic Structure Building',
    'getUserMobilePhoneNumber' => 'Get User Mobile Phone Number',
    'bandGuitar1' => 'Band Guitar 1',
    'band2Guitar123' => 'Band 2 Guitar 123',
);

foreach ($tests AS $input => $expected) {
    $output = preg_replace(array('/(?<=[^A-Z])([A-Z])/', '/(?<=[^0-9])([0-9])/'), ' $0', $input);
    $output = ucwords($output);
    echo $output .' : '. ($output == $expected ? 'PASSED' : 'FAILED') .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap the output from `preg_replace` with `trim` to remove the space that it prepends to the string.

Comment: @simshaun. Test passes if acronym is inside string but fails when string begins or ends with acronym.  thanks

Comment: Bug in yuor code:

CustomerIDWithSomeOtherJETWords => Customer IDWith Some Other JETWords

Comment: As others have indicated, this answer is not 100% reliable. https://3v4l.org/1KFKM

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on trying to parse PascalCase and camelCase strings into space-delimited titlecase.  The in-pattern comments should help to describe what each subpattern is doing.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/J3NsP))

```
$tests = [
    'LocalBusiness' => 'Local Business',
    'CivicStructureBuilding' => 'Civic Structure Building',
    'getUserMobilePhoneNumber' => 'Get User Mobile Phone Number',
    'bandGuitar1' => 'Band Guitar 1',
    'band2Guitar123' => 'Band 2 Guitar 123',
    'CustomerIDWithSomeOtherJETWords' => 'Customer ID With Some Other JET Words',
    'noOneIsMightierThanI' => 'No One Is Mightier Than I',
    'USAIsNumber14' => 'USA Is Number 14',
    '99LuftBallons' => '99 Luft Ballons',
];

$result = [];
foreach ($tests as $input => $expected) {
    $newString = ucwords(
        preg_replace(
            '/(?:
               [A-Z]+?         (?=\d|[A-Z][a-z])  #acronyms
               |[A-Z]?[a-z]+   (?=[^a-z])         #words
               |\d+            (?=\D)             #numbers
               |(*SKIP)(*FAIL)                    #abort
              )\K
             /x',
            ' ',
            $input
        )
    );
    $result[] = ($newString === $expected ? 'PASSED' : 'FAILED') . ': "' . $newString . '"';
}
var_export($result);
```

- `acronyms` are found by matching 1 or more uppercase letters followed by either a number or a word.
- `words` are found by matching lowercase letters which may or may not be preceded by an uppercase letter.
- `numbers` are found by matching 1 or more digits which are followed by a non-digit.
- anything that does not match should be prohibited from qualifying for space injection.